# Origine dell'espressione "passare di cibo"

Tags: meaning, regional, history, phrase-origin

Sempre più frequentemente, a seguito di una variazione delle mie abitudini alimentari, sento l'espressione "timore di passare di cibo" come riferimento, ironico, al fatto che tendo a mangiare di meno. L'unica informazione che sono riuscita a ricavare chiedendo a coloro i quali adottano una simile espressione è che le sue origini risalgono *ai tempi della guerra* (quale? La seconda guerra mondiale, forse?), ma nulla di più, e anche le ricerche fatte in rete si sono rivelate infruttuose.

Dunque mi rivolgo a voi: avete mai sentito usare simili parole? Se sì, in che contesto? Ne conoscete l'origine? 

 Non credo si tratti di un regionalismo; in ogni caso, se può aiutare, vengo dalla Campania.

Comment: Per quel che vale, sono di Roma e non l'ho mai sentito (e mi sembra che neanche Google o Google Books lo conoscano).

Comment: Mai sentito,  né in Puglia né in Lombardia.

Comment: @mrmld puoi specificare meglio o darci un esempio di un dialogo: sono altre persone che dicono "tu hai il timore di passare di cibo" o sono loro stessi che hanno il timore che tu "passi di cibo"? La guerra a cui ti riferisci è probabilmente la seconda guerra mondiale. In ogni caso non ho mai sentito questa espressione (in Veneto).

Comment: Well, I am just starting to study Italian, but in American English we have a saying along the lines of - "He is afraid to pass up a meal."  The meaning of this infers that the subject wants/needs to eat now, because they do not know when or where the next meal is coming from.  I guess that could be connected to war, or economic depressions, etc.

Comment: @PaoloFranchi, è la prima delle situazioni da te ipotizzate ed è legata ad un disturbo del comportamento alimentare che ho sviluppato. Ad esempio se mi reco a casa di qualcuno e mi viene offerto del cibo, al mio rifiuto mi viene chiesto: «Hai paura di *passare di cibo*?», per ironizzare sulla mia decisione. Ritieni che la guerra alla base di tale espressione sia il secondo conflitto mondiale per via dell'introduzione dei [razionamenti](http://www.panenostro.com/tessera-del-pane/)?

Comment: No, pensavo alla seconda guerra mondiale principalmente perché è l'unica e la più importante che le persone in vita ricordano (direttamente o attraverso racconti di prima mano) e perché ha avuto grande influenza sulla popolazione civile (il cosiddetto fronte interno)

Comment: @Msfolly, thank you for your comment, it's really interesting. I'm afraid the meaning of the Italian saying doesn't connote "fear of *skipping* a meal", but rather "fear of *having* a meal and thus exceed the daily intake of calories".

Comment: @Msfolly some remarks about your comment. (1) "cibo" is the italian for "food", "pasto" would be more appropriate for "meal", (2) it's "passare di cibo" (pass of/because food), not "passare il cibo" (pass *the* food), (3) as mrnld pointed out, the meaning is the opposite of what you wrote about "he is afraid to pass up a meal"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fornisco qui una mia interpretazione, basata più su impressioni personali che su fonti verificabili.

"Passare" potrebbe significare "morire": si veda http://www.dizionario-italiano.it/dizionario-italiano.php alla voce passare (verbo intransitivo, punto 21). In ogni caso, potrebbe essere una variazione di "trapassare".

"Di cibo" sarebbe dunque un complemento di causa (come in "morire di peste").

A questo punto "avere il timore di passare di cibo" significherebbe "avere il timore di morire per il troppo cibo", e quindi si adatta ad una situazione di rifiuto del cibo.

Infine, il collegamento con la guerra. In un tempo in cui il cibo scarseggia, si capisce che l'atto di rifiutare del cibo possa destare molta sorpresa e incredulità, al punto che chi volesse commentare con ironia, stravolgerebbe la situazione attribuendo il rifiuto alla volontà di non morire per il troppo cibo (quando è evidente che mangiare non farebbe comunque male, anzi).

Comment: Mi sembra una spiegazione molto valida, grazie!